# Prolog, how to show multiple output in write()

Tags: prolog

```
go :-   match(Mn,Fn),
        write('--Matching Result--'),
        nl,
        write(Mn),
        write(' match with '),
        write(Fn),
        match(Mn1,Fn1).


person(may,female,25,blue).
person(rose,female,20,blue).
person(hock,male,30,blue).
person(ali,male,24,blue).
match(Mn,Fn):-person(Fn,'female',Fage,Fatt),
person(Mn,'male',Mage,Matt),
Mage>=Fage,
Fatt=Matt.
```

Hi,this is my code...but it's only can show the 1 output...but there are 3 pair of matching in match(X,Y).how to show them all in my go function.

Thank you

Comment: If you want your code to look good in SO, indent it with 4 spaces or select all your code and press the `{}` button.

Answer (score 11):

You get all your matches if you force backtracking, usually by entering `;` (e.g. in SWI Prolog). But you also see that you are getting unnecessary outputs `true`. This is because the last clause in `go` is `match(Mn1,Fn1)`. This clause succeeds three times and binds the variables `Mn1,Fn1` but then only `true` is output, because you do not `write()` after that clause. The fourth time `match(Mn1,Fn1)` fails and by backtracking you come back to the first clause `match(Mn,Fn)` that matches, the match is output, etc.

You surely do not want to have this behavior. You should remove the last clause `match(Mn1,Fn1)` in `go`. Now by pressing `;` you get the 3 matches without any output `true` in between.

But what you likely want is that the program does the backtracking. To achieve this, you just need to force backtracking by adding `false` as the last clause. To get proper formatting of the output, use the following program. The last clause `go2.` is added to get `true` at the very end.

```
go2 :- write('--Matching Result--'), nl,
    match(Mn,Fn),
    write(Mn), write(' match with '), write(Fn), nl,
    fail.
go2.
```

This technique is called *failure driven loop*.

Answer (score 3):

If you have any predicate that has multiple results and want to to find all of them, you should use `findall/3`

For example, in your case, you could do something like:

```
findall([X,Y], match(X,Y),L).
```

L will be a list that will contain all the X,Y that satisfy match(X,Y) in the format [X,Y].
for example, assuming that:

```
match(m1,f1).
match(m2,f2).
```

the result will be L = [ [m1,f1], [m2,f2] ]

note that you can define the format as you wish, for example you could write:

```
findall(pair(X,Y), match(X,Y), L).
L = [ pair(m1,f1), pair(m2,f2) ]

findall( X, match(X,Y), L).
L = [ m1, m2]

findall( 42, match(X,Y), L).
L = [42, 42]
```

then you have to recurse on the list to print them.

However, if you wish to find one result, run some code and then continue you could use forall/2:

```
forall(match(X,Y), my_print(X,Y).
```

Answer (score -1):

Prolog is a lazy language. Which means that it will stop once it has found a condition that made your problem true. This will be the very first match alone.

IF your code is working (I haven't tried it), then you should try and run the `match`-statement like this in your prolog inspector: `match(X,Y)`

The prolog inspector will return all states and print them for you.

Comment: i know, i can show them all through match(X,Y).Is there any other way to show the rest in my go function? but not match(X,Y).

Comment: I do realise what you mean my lazy language here; however I think that it's kinda misleading since most of the times lazy refers to lazy evaluation (which prolog doesn't really have)