# print all records using query in prolog

Tags: prolog

```
lectures(monday, nolecture).
lectures(tuesday, vp).
lectures(tuesday, se).
lectures(tuesday, ddbms).
lectures(wednessday, ds).
lectures(wednessday, mpl).
lectures(thursday, vp).
lectures(thrusday, se).
lectures(friday, ds).
lectures(friday, mpl).
lectures(saturday, ai).
lectures(saturday, ddbms).

?- lectures(friday, X), write(X),nl.
```

the query print only first record as **ds** only, I want to print all record on particular day i.e Friday, the result should be **ds** and **mpl**.

update me!

Comment: is prolog actually used in the 'real' world?

Comment: @MitchWheat: Does it matter? It's still a valid question. And yes, it's used.

Comment: @aqua: never said it wasn't a valid question. Care to educate on where it's used?  And what I can't ask a question in comments?  Is this a homework question???

Comment: yes! it use in Artificial intelligence

Comment: Used in AI and Database applications as already stated.

Comment: Database applications? I haven't seen it used in any Database applications in the last 10 years. Bet you Facebook et al. aren't using prolog in their Database applications!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prolog, how to show multiple output in write()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349408/prolog-how-to-show-multiple-output-in-write)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add `fail.` to the end of your query:

```
| ?- lectures(friday, X), write(X), nl, fail.
ds
mpl

no
| ?-
```

Also see [this very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349408/prolog-how-to-show-multiple-output-in-write) so try to use search a little bit more before asking a new question.

Comment: thanks for answer and fruitful link. your answer is accepted!

Comment: For the record, this is called a *failure-driven loop*.

Answer (score 6):

btw if you want to make it more usable, you could wrap it in a predicate :

```
display_lectures(Day) :-
    lectures(Day, X),
    write(X),
    nl,
    fail
    ;
    true.
```

The important addition to your version or [@aqua](https://stackoverflow.com/users/572097/aqua)'s one here is the disjunction with true. It'll make this call usable in a larger predicate so I'd thought I'd mention it.

And alternatively, here is another way to do it (if your implementation has some sort of `forall/2`) :

```
display_lectures(Day) :- forall(lectures(Day, X), (write(X), nl)).
```

Comment: You can easily roll your own `forall/2` : `forall(Goal1, Goal2) :- not((Goal1, not(Goal2))).`. ;-)

Comment: as would say some prologs : `true.`! Thanks for the addition :)